# how to convert whole array to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I got a question in the interview that he asked to convert the whole array into a String. I tried with toString() but that's not worked for his output.

input

```
let a=['20','30','50']
```

expected output

```
"['20','30','50']"
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to turn the array into JSON? `JSON.stringify(a)`?

Comment: JSON.stringify([1, 2 3])

Comment: @Ifaruki Your solution is wrong, it accepts a array as param not a string

Comment: That expected output isn't a valid string in any syntax. Is that meant to be an example string as the console might display it? Are the outer quotes meant to be part of the string?

Comment: `"['" + ['20','30','50'].join("','") + "']"` could make use of [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Follow on question... how is the result supposed to be displayed? Where is it _"output"_ to?

Comment: @Grumpy i know, i editet it already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the *"output"* is the **content** of this string you want, you can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the values first to wrap them in single-quotes, then join the array with commas and wrap the entire thing in `"[...]"`.

```js
const a = ['20','30','50'];

const str = `"[${a.map(v=>`'${v}'`).join(",")}]"`;

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let arr = ['1','2','3'];

//this will convert it to string
let arrToString = JSON.stringify(arr);

//you can confirm its type using below code
console.log(typeof(arrToString))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).